# Symbolic integration of product of Hankel function and trigonometric function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to perform the following integration.

My function is : $r \cos(r) H_0^{(2)}(k r)$. I want to integrate from $0$ to $\pi$, and want to get the expression in terms of $k$. I used this command:

```
Integrate[r*cos[r]*HankelH2[0,k*r],{r,0,pi}]
```

The integral is not performed. Please suggest some solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I edited the code to format it properly.  I left `cos` as is.  It should be `Cos`, but I could be sure whether it was a simple typo, or an error.  Do you have a reason to think it is known how to write the integral in terms *Mathematica* functions?

Comment: `int[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[r*Cos[r] HankelH2[0, k*r], {r, 0, Pi}]` gives you a way to represent the function via numerical approximation.

Comment: There is no closed form solution for `Integrate[BesselJ[0, k r] Cos[r], r]` which what causes this to fail. There is a analytical solution for k=1. `k = 1; Integrate[r*Cos[r]*HankelH2[0, k*r], r]` gives `1/4 (2 r^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 3/4}, {1/2, 1/2, 2}, -r^2]- I Sqrt[2] MeijerG[{{1, 5/4, 7/4}, {1/2}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1/2, 3/2, 3/2}}, r, 1/2])` might also be better to ask this on the math group.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you very much for your replies. Actually i can not put the value k=1, because I want to solve the result of integral (which should be in terms of k) to find roots of equation i.e. the values of k.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thankyou very much for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment and to include the purpose finding roots

```
ClearAll[int, intjac];

int[k_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] := 
  NIntegrate[r*Cos[r] HankelH2[0, k*r], {r, 0, Pi}, opts];

intjac[k0_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] :=
  Block[{k}, {{NIntegrate[D[r*Cos[r] HankelH2[0, k*r], k] /. k -> k0, {r, 0, Pi}, opts]}}];
```

The Jacobian `intjac` is passed to `FindRoot` to use in Newton's method.  This can **sometimes** help speed convergence.  In this case both the function and the Jacobian are moderately expensive numerical integrations.  It happens to help reduced the time by half in the test case below. Note: The Jacobian has to have a matrix value; hence the `{{}}` to turn the derivative into a 1 x 1 matrix.

I would suggest using a finite `AccuracyGoal`.  The default for `NIntegrate` is `Infinity` and `NIntegrate` will complain (`NIntegrate::slwcon` and `NIntegrate::ncvb`) when `FindRoot` drives `k` near a root.  At a root, by definition, the integral is zero, and it's impossible to achieve any `PrecisionGoal` in computing a value of zero.  Setting a finite accuracy goal prevents `NIntegrate` from refining the integration further than it can at `MachinePrecision`.  For a higher `AccuracyGoal`, the `WorkingPrecision` would have to be increased.

```
(sol = FindRoot[int[k, AccuracyGoal -> 15], {k, -0.01}, Jacobian -> intjac[k]]) // AbsoluteTiming
int[k, AccuracyGoal -> 15] /. sol
(*
  {0.447269, {k -> -3.19371*10^-20 - 0.520674 I}}
  2.74622*10^-20 + 8.32667*10^-17 I
*)

(sol = FindRoot[int[k, AccuracyGoal -> 15], {k, -0.01}]) // AbsoluteTiming
int[k, AccuracyGoal -> 15] /. sol
(*
  {0.821435, {k -> 1.38324*10^-18 - 0.520674 I}}
  -1.18942*10^-18 + 8.32667*10^-17 I
*)
```